# Logo too similar or not?

Tags: logo, shapes, copyright, business, legal

Hi we have a logo I designed, it is UK trademarked registered, we recently asked a company in the USA to help market us, and the said that we would have to change our name etc, as it was too similar to theirs. We had no idea they existed until we were given their details by a third party. Names etc we can change no real issue. They are insinuating we copied their name, logo etc. and are threatening a cease & desist order. Question is how similar are they, are they distinguishable enough?

I am biased, so what do you guys and girls think?

Adidas is three stripes, Tesla model 3 is three stripes.

Our thumbnail logo:

[image]

Their company thumbnail:

[image]

Their main logo also gives their company name to the right, our does not, it’s just the image.

Many thanks in advance for taking the time to read this question and give your opinion.

Comment: There is no similarity between these logos in my opinion. But my opinion doesn't matter. Hire a lawyer who specialises in trademarks if you want proper legal advice. Please don't ask for legal advice here. It's off-topic

Comment: Thanks, appreciate no legal advice, none is requested, just opinion on if you think they are similar or not, the situation is just for context.

Comment: That's the problem though. It's not our opinions that count in such cases. It's up to a judge.  You need a lawyer to represent you, not opinions form random people on the internet. Also questions seeking opinions are subjective, and ultimately not what GDSE is about.

Comment: I googled the two logos to get more info on the companies. Seems you are operating in the same field (more or less) and that your names only differ by one letter. This seems legally much more complicated than just to establish if the two logos are similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other 3-striped logos out there — I don't see an immediate connection between your logo and the other one. Also quite far from Adidas and Tesla aswell.

Now, if they are prepared to take legal action, our opinions here are more or less pointless, and you will ultimately need legal advice.

Honestly you may consider changing your logo under the circumstances, there are better ways to combine a V and/or 3 stripes anyway.